# IndexError: index out of range in self - Transformers Module, using Pegasus Model for Paraphrasing

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

So I'm using Transformers library and using the model "Pegasus" for Paraphrasing news articles, etc that I scrape online. I split the articles into sentences using NLTK library "sent_tokenize" and then run each sentence through Pegasus, however, I keep getting the error "IndexError: index out of range in self" and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong or how to fix.

Text: "Soon thereafter, the whites (conjunctiva) and corneas of the eyes may become dry and thick—a condition called xerophthalmia Keratomalacia Keratomalacia is an eye disorder that involves drying and clouding of the cornea (the clear layer in front of the iris and pupil) due to vitamin A deficiency in people with undernutrition."

Code:

```
def get_response(input_text,num_return_sequences):
  batch = tokenizer.prepare_seq2seq_batch([input_text],padding='longest',max_length=1024, return_tensors="pt").to(torch_device)
  translated = model.generate(**batch,max_length=1024,num_beams=10, num_return_sequences=num_return_sequences, temperature=1.5)
  tgt_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(translated, skip_special_tokens=True)
  return tgt_text

introduction_list = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(introtext)
for phrase in introduction_list:
   if len(phrase) > 15 and len(phrase) < 1024:
        para_phrases = get_response(phrase, 1)
```

The error is triggering in:

```
translated = model.generate(**batch,max_length=1024,num_beams=10, num_return_sequences=num_return_sequences, temperature=1.5)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2044, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
IndexError: index out of range in self
```

Comment: How did you load tokenizer and model?

Comment: Also, please include the full stack-trace.

Comment: did you ever solve this?  I have the same error...